# T24 cannot find a class after install, need more configuration?

Tags: class, banking, core-banking

I am quite new to TEMENOS t24, as this is my first install of the application. Sorry if this is too basic, but I am rather lost here, so please bear with me and help me out if you can:

After completing the install of Model Bank on my test server, I get the following error after trying to run the tRun EX command from console:

> Cannot find 'EX' (class : 'com.temenos.t24.EX_cl')

The TAFJ installer gave no error whatsoever, and I double-checked all the directories and files copied from TAFJ_HOME to my T24_HOME, and they appear to be the same, same file and folders size and same number of files and folders as well, so it doesn't seem to be anything "missing" from my installation.

Could it be a configuration issue? Is there another path or tafj.properties entry that I could be missing? btw, it's a Windows install that I am trying here, if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide in order for me to finish this install.

Answer (score 1):

EX is a T24 program which is the entry point to login to T24.

*tShow EX* - This commnad should show you the java class path for this Program.

If not, Please make sure if you have the proper classpath setup in tafj.properties

*temn.tafj.directory.precompile=/../../T24/T24lib*

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by copying complete t24lib jars , issue was coming because earlier few jars were not copied properly and size was showing 0 kb.